# How to post a message on linkedin in android?

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I am new to android.In my application , there is a requirement that when i click on share button i need to share something on linked in wall.How can i do ? please can any one help me.

Thanking in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well I am using [socialauth for android](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/) for posting my messages on linkedin and twitter.

and for more basic approach you can go through [this](http://www.sourcetricks.com/index.php/category/android-linkedin-oauth-implementation/)

Here is an example for socialauth :

First you have to download socialauth-android-sdk-2.0.zip from [here](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/downloads/detail?name=socialauth-android-sdk-2.0.zip)

then copy jar from dist folder and paste it in libs folder of your project.

Now,

Register your application on [linkedin](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication) and get API key and secret key

Copy file "oauth_consumer.properties" from assets folder of zip to assets folder of your project and also edit this file and write your API key and secret key in linkedin section

```
#LinkedIn
api.linkedin.com.consumer_key = *************
api.linkedin.com.consumer_secret = **************
```

also get drawable of linkedin from any example provided in example folder of zip.

finally, change your activity accordingly (activity given below),

```
public class ShareActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText shareText; 

    SocialAuthAdapter shareAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.share_layout);  

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.share);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);

        ImageView product_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.share_image);

        shareText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.share_text);

        shareAdapter = new SocialAuthAdapter(new ResponseListener());

        shareAdapter.addProvider(Provider.LINKEDIN, R.drawable.linkedin);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {


        case R.id.share:
            shareAdapter.authorize(this, Provider.LINKEDIN);
            break;
        }

    }

    private final class ResponseListener implements DialogListener {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {


            shareAdapter.updateStatus(shareText.getText().toString());

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Posted",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(SocialAuthError e) {
            Log.v("Share", "OMG ERROR!!!!" + e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // Toast.makeText(Share.this, "Cancelled",
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onBack() {
            // Toast.makeText(Share.this, "Back", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: by using socialauth example nothing is happening.

Comment: but,how can i post in face book and twitter.

Comment: In similar way... Just add provider for Facebook and Twitter

Comment: i added provider for Facebook and twitter.authentication is working but any message didn't post on wall.Here my code is:shareAdapter.addProvider(Provider.LINKEDIN, R.drawable.linkedin);
        shareAdapter.addProvider(Provider.FACEBOOK, R.drawable.facebook);
     
        shareAdapter.enable(button); public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {


        case R.id.share:
            shareAdapter.authorize(this, Provider.LINKEDIN);
            shareAdapter.authorize(this, Provider.FACEBOOK);
            break;
        }

    }

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it can solve your issue

```
share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override

 public void onClick(View v) {

        String share = et.getText().toString();
        if (null != share && !share.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

            OAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(Config.LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_KEY, Config.LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_SECRET);
            consumer.setTokenWithSecret(accessToken.getToken(), accessToken.getTokenSecret());

            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares");
            try {
                consumer.sign(post);
            } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } // here need the consumer for sign in for post the share
            post.setHeader("content-type", "text/XML");
            byte[] data = null;
         try {
        ileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(imgUrl1);
        Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
               bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        data = baos.toByteArray();  
        }
          catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
           { 
         e.printStackTrace();
     Log.d("onCreate", "debug error  e = " + e.toString());
       }     

     String myEntity = "<share><comment>"+  text +"</comment>    <content><submitted-image-url>data</submitted-image-url></content><visibility><code>anyone</code></visibility></share>";

          try {
                post.setEntity(new StringEntity(myEntity));
                org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);
                Toast.makeText(LinkedInSampleActivity.this,
                        "Shared sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(LinkedInSampleActivity.this,
                    "Please enter the text to share",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

}